# Adding private ssh key to docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to add my ssh private key to docker, my Dockerfile is as follows:

```
ARG key
RUN echo $key > panaxea-key

RUN chmod 600 panaxea-key
RUN eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add panaxea-key
```

Console output:

```
Step 10/14 : RUN echo $key > panaxea-key
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ee023dba45e
Step 11/14 : RUN chmod 600 panaxea-key
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b7c42a9c5268
Step 12/14 : RUN eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add panaxea-key
 ---> Running in 9895e087cea5
Agent pid 9
Enter passphrase for panaxea-key: The command '/bin/sh -c eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add panaxea-key' returned a non-zero code: 1
dario@dario-X750JB:~/Panaxea_Docker$
```

Any advice? My key doesn't have a passphrase

Comment: It might have something to do with the ssh-add operation doing it in non-interactive mode. The raw text you're providing of course, doesn't have a key, but when it gets created it may expect to have one. I know that when you do ssh-keygen -t rsa, it will normally prompt you for a passphrase. Why don't you try creating the key outside of docker and using the COPY operation to just put it into the image instead? Would be a better test.

Comment: “Don’t do it!”  It’s extremely easy to get the key out of the image once it’s built, and at that point you’d basically have to consider it compromised and revoke access to anything it had access to.

Comment: @DavidMaze can you suggest an alternative please?

Comment: Why do you think you want it?  Often the answers turn into things like “check the Dockerfile into the git repository, don’t try to clone the repository inside the Dockerfile” and other higher-level things like that.

Comment: @DavidMaze because I have to clone a private git repository into my docker environment? :/

Answer (score 0):

If your key doesn't have a passphrase and ssh-add is asking you for one, it means ssh-add could not understand your key file. The culprit is `echo $key > panaxea-key`. You'll see that the file is a single line of text now and all the newlines have disappeared.

Use `echo "$key" > panaxea-key` instead.

This should get it to work, but the warnings about embedding a private key inside a docker image still stand. How you get around that depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I feel like that's a different question altogether.